# Jolt Transform specification Issue

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

My current input JSON is

```json
[
  {
    "id": "hjahskjjks",
    "key1": "Room Admin",
    "key2": "08-12-2018 09:29",
    "key3": 31,
    "key4": "jkjlkkl"
  }
]
```

I want output JSON like below. All I need to add one extra key and value 'key5'

Expected output

```json
[
  {
    "id": "hjahskjjks",
    "key1": "Room Admin",
    "key2": "08-12-2018 09:29",
    "key3": 31,
    "key4": "jkjlkkl",
    "key5": "hjjhjk"
  }
]
```

And also mention how to override value of key4

Kindly help me to find Jolt Json Specification for this.

Below is the spec i used

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "key5": "dd"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more level of nesting in order to roam within the nested object such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key5": "hjjhjk"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and if you wanna replace `key4` with `key5` then just use again

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key4": "hjjhjk"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

So, that spec will update *the value* if *the key name* already exists, otherwise it will insert a *new key-value* pair

Case 1 :

[image]

Case 2 :

[image]

Comment: Thank u for your great support. This is working fine.

Comment: you're welcome @akshayk.k